# Extended WPF Toolkit Use

Tags: expression-blend

I found this toolkit and was wondering how can you get the controls in the DLL to show up as assets when using Expression Blend 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a WPF project and add a reference to the controls. They **should** show up then.

Comment: I followed your steps and it did not show up.  Closed the application, reopened and there they were.  Thanks!